# How to create flatlist auto scroll with Hooks in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an auto scroll flatlist carousel that can also allow the user to scroll manually. The problem is that I get this error `flatListRef.scrollToIndex is not a function`. I tried searching how other people create an auto scroll flatlist but their solution is using class.

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null)
useEffect (() => { 
    const totalIndex = data.length - 1;
    setInterval (() => {
        if(flatListRef.current.index < totalIndex) {
            flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: flatListRef.current.index + 1})
        } else {
            flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0})
        }
    }, 3000)
}, []);

const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.cardView}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} resizeMode="contain"/>
        </View>
    )
} 
return (
    <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 10}} >
        <FlatList 
            ref={flatListRef}
            data={data} 
            keyExtractor={data => data.id}
            horizontal
            pagingEnabled
            scrollEnabled
            snapToAlignment="center"
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            decelerationRate={"fast"}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
            persistentScrollbar={true}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        /> 
    </View>
);
```

styles:

```
cardView: {
    flex: 1, 
    width: width - 20,  
    height: height * 0.21,
    backgroundColor: Colors.empty,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center', 
},
image: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.empty,
    width: width - 20,  
    height: height * 0.21,
},
```

Comment: I think you need to console your `ref` so you at least know what props you getting from your element ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useRef returns a mutable object whose .current property is initialized to initial value. So basically you need to access scrollIndex like this

```
flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: flatListRef.current.index + 1})
```

**Edit**: To answer your comment, you should've asked directly for auto-scrolling, however, The code below should work!

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null)
let index=0;
const totalIndex = datas.length - 1;

  useEffect (() => { 
  setInterval (() => {
  index++;
  if(index < totalIndex) {
      flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: index})
  } else {
      flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0})
  }
  }, 1000)
  }, []);
```

Comment: I tried your method and the error is gone but the flatlist is not auto scrolling

Comment: Refer to the edit @Irfan

Comment: thank you so much for this but I have a problem. Let say I have 3 images in the flatlist. When I try to manually scroll to the end it supposed to automatically scroll back to the beginning but instead it goes to the second image. I think it is because it doesnt actually refer what index the flatlist is currently in. How do I fix that?

Comment: check out https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel , I believe this will solve your problem. Look into pull requests to make this library work

Answer (score 0):

as per the guide on [React Native onScrollToIndexFailed](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#onscrolltoindexfailed) 
you have to override

```
onScroll={(e) => {
            this.setState({ currentIndex: Math.floor(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / (dimensions.wp(this.props.widthPercent || 100) - 1)) });
          }}
onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
            const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            wait.then(() => {
flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: 0, animated: true });
            });
          }}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work. I got the same error

Comment: @Irfan can you please use refs as ```flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex``` in FC

Answer (score 0):

Just use `scrollToEnd()` method in useEffect with a useRef on the Flatlist.

Example :

```
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);
  const data = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3']; // Dummies datas

  useEffect(() => {
    // Scroll to the bottom when data change
    flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        onContentSizeChange={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```